# After Effects - How to avoid annoying gradations if I render a mp4?

Tags: after-effects, animation-rendering

I created a light in After Effects. My **preview works** as expected:

[image]

But if I render my composition as a mp4 file, I get these strange **gradations errors**:

[image]

I've tried every option in the comp settings, but the error still appears.

What I can do to get rid of it?

Comment: Interesting question. I was always thinking that was a upload problem.I did a little research and I found  this [explanation by Grayscalegorilla](https://vimeo.com/6984755). Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 5):

That's called: Banding. About **Color Banding** from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding):

> Colour banding is a problem of inaccurate colour presentation in computer graphics. In 24 bit colour modes, 8 bits per channel is usually considered sufficient to render images in Rec. 709 or sRGB. However, in some cases there is a risk of producing abrupt changes between shades of the same colour. For instance, displaying natural gradients (like sunsets, dawns or clear blue skies) can show minor banding.

In your case I assume that this is a compression issue. Movie containers like: mov, avi or mp4 only can have 8bit, but the preview is in 16bit or 32bit. If you render a **image** format that supports 16bit or 32bit (preferably exr, tga, tiff) **instead of a video** you should see no difference to your preview screenshot.

The simplest way to avoid banding is to **add grain** to your video.

- One option is to use **generated grain** shipped by default with After Effects. Just typing `Add Grain` in the `Effects & Presets window` and apply this effect to your final comp. Note: A Intensity value of 0.37 or 0.4 should be enough to remove the banding and makes the effect not noticeable.
- Another option is to use scanned **film grain** from real cameras

Comment: or and make your white slightly impure

Comment: Thanks @joojaa! Do you mean a little bit more greyish?

Comment: no off color as in little bluish yellow or

Comment: @joojaa Yes can help, but depends on the footage you have and how much you can influence the appearance of the video. The advantage of adding grain is that it helps in all cases.

Comment: sure but you can combine it with grain to minimize grainyness.

Comment: @joojaa You are right. Thanks! Combining both techniques makes sense. I will update the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: you guys are awesome in it worked even tho it effected a little bit on the quietly but its a price ill pay to get redof banding

Comment: A downside to this technique of course is that noise and grain adversely affect how well it will compress, so that you'll need a higher bit-rate for the same quality. It's still the best solution, but that's something you may need to consider.